# Help rendering map

Tags: list, csom

Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620085/need-help-from-sharepoint-experts-creating-map-from-list-using-js

I dont feel like retyping the whole thing, just read this and let me know your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

Try using
`clientContext.load(this.collListItem);` instead of `clientContext.load(collListItem);` and `clientContext.load(this.website);` instead of `clientContext.load(website);`

Comment: Did not work, but i still added it to the code, i got it to work by re organizing my entire code. But a new problem came up. Thanks!

Comment: You need to wait for the sp.js loads. Instead of the retrieveListItems() at the end, put this: `$(document).ready(function() { ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, "sp.js"); }); );`